# Visual Studio 2008 + Windows 7: Setup Projects hanging

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, setup-deployment

We have Visual Studio 2008 Team System (SP1) installed on Windows 7 on a 64-bit desktop machine.

Our solutions contain setup and deployment projects (vdproj).

When Visual Studio loads, it hangs trying to load the setup projects.

This also happens to newly created solutions entirely in this environment so it is not something lagging from old files or environments.

Here is my test solution structure:

MyTestSolution
 - MyTestProject
   - Program.cs (Contains Console.WriteLine("Hello World"))
 - MyTestSetupProject (When creating it hangs)

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Does VS2008 need to be run as administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the issue that was causing Setup and Deployment projects to hang while trying to load them.

This [MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/9a0b3699-7109-4ac4-bd77-3efc8b841c27/) has the solution:

Basically it is failing authentication when retrieving references for visual studio.

I always thought it would be the "Zusätzliche Sicherheit für Verweisprotokollierung"!!

Thanks for your help everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, VS 2008 was hanging when loading the Setup Project within the solution. I had a look at the solution linked by Russell but the option was already unticked.

Everything seemed to point towards a permission issue, so I ran the VS as Administrator and it has worked fine.

Unsure of root cause, but this will do for me. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, running as Admin didn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark - but have you tried disabling IntelliSense (code completion)? I had a very similier problem with earlier versions of VS.

Comment: Hi fupsduck, thanks for your suggestion, I did this with no success.

Comment: Btw, I didn't give you the -1.

Comment: I didn't think so Russell. To who did - the discription of the problem was similiar to one I solved by my sugestion! I clearly said it was a shot in the dark. No good deed goes unpunished.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try opening a command-line and using the following command:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /SafeMode
```

If on x64 windows 7 then change to Program Files (x86)

If this works then you have a problem with your 3rd-Party plugins.

Comment: Thanks, problem still occurs when running in safe mode.